# C# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode HTML Entity in xml add extra &amp

Tags: c#, xml, character-encoding

```
 TitleText.InnerText = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text)
```

or

```
TitleText.InnerXml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text)
```

will result with `&amp;#232` instead of &#232

Comment: That is correct, it does what it's supposed to. See duplicate for solutions.

Comment: the final result for a html entity should not look like this &#232 ? and how i am supposed to achieve it. &amp;#232 is not a double encoding ?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/tryit.asp?deci=152&ent=tilde